# req.user is undefined and I am desperate (google oauth 2)

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js, mern

I hosted my MERN app on a domain, I allowed URIs and JS origins in the google console but my auth is still not working, the issue is that when i `fetch('https://example.net/auth/login/success')` on the front end it returns undefined and the err 403, same goes for when I console.log the user in the server code, it is undefined

```
router.get('/login/success', (req, res) => {
    console.log("REQ.USER")
    console.log(req.user) //ALWAYS UNDEFINED <----------
    if(req.user){
        res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            message: 'success',
            user: req.user,
            cookies: req.cookies
        });
    }else{
        res.status(403).json({error: true, message: 'Not Authorized'})
    }
})
```

but when I enter `https://example.net/auth/login/success` in the URL bar it returns a json of the user as it should so thats weird

I tried logging the user out in `passport.serializeUser` and `passport.deserializeUser` and the user there is not undefined, it logs out a full object with the users google info.

I really dont know what to do and what to try next anybody got any suggestions?

This is my index.js mw

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '100mb' }));

app.use(cookieSession(
  {
    name: "session",
    keys:['weerit'],
    maxAge: 24*60*60*1000
  }
))

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(cors({
  origin: [process.env.FRONTEND_URL, process.env.BACKEND_URL],
  methods: 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,PATCH',
  credentials: true
}));

app.use('/auth', authRoute);
app.use('/api/users', userRoutes);
app.use('/api/listings', listingRoutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/login/success', passport.authenticate('google'), (req, res) => {
  // rest of your code
})
```

Comment: idk anymore i tried it it didnt help, i dont know why but as soon as i change the env variables to the real domain it just wont work